# Maven, eclipse, servlet api 3.1.0. Eclipse complains "cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1"

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlet-3.1

I created a webapp using the maven simple webapp archetype, and then added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also changed the `web.xml` file to use version 3.1:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
```

I changed the java compiler version to 1.8.  Eclipse now complains:

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1.
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
```

Any idea how to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
in your project directory.

.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs, change to 1.8

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters=do not generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8  
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
change jst.web version to 3.1, java version to 1.8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
<fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
<installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>
<installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>
</faceted-project>
```

then import your project again.
hope this helps